# Is there a higher chance of a coin landing heads if it just landed on tails?

Tags: probability

if you flipped a coin and it landed on tails, is there a higher probability of it landing on heads on the next flip?

Comment: Not if your coin is fair

Comment: This is called the *gambler’s fallacy*. Did you do any research before posting this question? You are expected to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This depends! If the question is about abstract, mathematical coins you can find in probability books, the answer **no** given by the other answers here is the right one.

But, lets say you are actually asking about actual, physical coin-tossing, then this becomes an empirical question, so can only be answered with experiments and data.  One person who has looked into it that way is Persi Diaconis, see his youtube channel, for instance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obg7JPd6cmw  (which is 3min, other are much longer).

I forgot the details, but: If you throw the coin in the air and capture it in your hands, the probability that it will give the same probability as last throw is about 0.51. But, maybe one can train to get other probabilities ... If you let the coin fall on the floor, all bets are off. Then answer can depend on the individual coin!

Comment: The only correct answer.

Comment: 0.5 is "about" 0.51. You really need more rigorous statistics than he's providing to justify the conclusion you're reporting.

Comment: You will have to see his papers to get that kind of detail. When I have time (that will take weeks) I will search in them, and report details here. 0.51 is about the probability of a newborn being a boy, and it took statistical data (Laplace got birth protocols from Paris, around 1820) to see that is different from 0.50

Comment: All right. I'll try to look up those papers later, too. Aside from that, did you intend your answer to stop mid-sentence ("Then answer can depend on the" ...)? Did you forget to add or delete a few words?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The paper you're thinking of may be "Dynamical Bias in the Coin Toss" from SIAM Review 2007, freely available on [Professor Diaconis's web site](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/year.html). The details: In 27 tosses, they find that the probability that a tossed coin comes up the same way that it started in your hand is 0.508, with a standard deviation of 0.0125. No other analysis is reported, but I think 0.5 does fall outside the naive two-tailed 99% confidence interval of their result (but N = 27 only, so take that for what it's worth).

Answer (score 1):

No. This is called [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy).

Answer (score 1):

No. If the coin flipped is fair, the probability is still $50\%$. This is because on any given flip, the probability is the same since it is an independent event, which means that each flip does not affect the ones after them and is not affected by the previous ones. And, as Issac Browne said, this is called Gambler's Fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modeling the situation where the coin has a certain fixed probability of flipping heads with each toss, then it depends on what that fixed probability is. (And it is completely irrelevant what how the previous toss came out.) So if the coin is 60/40 for heads in general, it has a 60% chance to land heads that second time. But it would be misleading to think this had anything to do with the previous flip landing tails.

If you come at it with no certain fixed probability in place, and are gathering empirical evidence as to what the actual probability is, then you have some very very very weak evidence at this point that the coin is unfairly balanced towards tails, and the second flip is more likely to land tails too than heads.

These two approaches are called frequentist probability and Bayesian probability, and both are valued fields of study. The first kind uses simpler mathematical modeling, and is what more people will be familiar with from their undergraduate studies.